# My angularJS ng-model is shared across browser tabs. How to prevent that

Tags: angularjs, tabs, sharing, angular-ngmodel

My angularJS ng-model is shared across browser tabs. I want to maintain a separate scope for each tab. I am storing  data in  SessionStorage.I dont have any issues with SessionStorage  but ng-model which is having watcher, is shared across browser tabs. How to prevent that?

Comment: I had this issue tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

That is easy, there are hide options for it!
When your application starts to run at http://Localhost:3000, an other application start at http://localhost:3001. In this application there are some configuration that can be change, for example, Sync Options. 
You must navigate to http://localhost:3001 then select Sync Option and disable all option but CodeSync.