# Input field values appear on all local browser instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

I'm having an issue in my AngularJS application where anything I type into an input box in one browser appears in the same input box across multiple browsers on the same machine.

For instance, I open Chrome, Opera, and IE11 and point them to my app. When I start typing my login name into the box the value appears in the login name box across all browsers.

[image: value appearing across browsers]

This only occurs on my development machine. When I open the application on another computer, even in multiple browser instances, the input field values are not shared between browsers.

I really don't know what's going on here. I suspect that the  data is being shared between browsers but I'm not sure how, or why. Any ideas on how to make this stop are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ian

Here are some relevant pieces of code:

```js
vm.loginSubmit = function () {
 vm.error = null;

 vm.authService.login(vm.authRequest)
  .then(function (response) {
   vm.authService.tokenInfo = response.data;

   $window.sessionStorage.setItem("AuthenticationToken", JSON.stringify(vm.authService.tokenInfo));

   $.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function (result) {
     vm.hub.server.subscribe(vm.authService.tokenInfo.authenticationToken);
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
     vm.error = error;

    });
   

   $scope.$emit('loginNotification', vm.authService.tokenInfo);

   vm.authTokenTimerStart(vm.authService.tokenInfo.tokenExpiry);
  },
  function (error) {
   vm.authService.tokenInfo.error = error.data;
  }
 );
};
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" novalidate>
 <div layout="row" ng-if="!loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.isAuthenticated" style="text-align: left; justify-content: flex-end;">
  <div>
   <md-input-container md-no-float>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="loginPanelController.authRequest.username" />
   </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div>
   <md-input-container md-no-float>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginPanelController.authRequest.password" />
   </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div>
   <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="loginPanelController.loginSubmit()">
    <div layout="row">
     <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <div>Login</div>
    </div>
   </md-button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div layout="row" ng-if="loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.isAuthenticated" style="text-align: left; justify-content: flex-end;">
  <div style="align-self: center;">
   <label ng-if="!loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.firstName" style="margin-right: 5px; align-self: flex-end;">Hello {{loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.username}}</label>
   <label ng-if="loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.firstName" style="margin-right: 5px; align-self: flex-end;">Hello {{loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.firstName}}</label>
  </div>

  <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="loginPanelController.renew()">
   <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
    Reset authentication timeout
   </md-tooltip>
   <div layout="row">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x" style="margin-right: 3px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div>Renew Token ({{loginPanelController.authTokenTimeoutSeconds}})</div>
   </div>
  </md-button>
  <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="loginPanelController.logout()">
   <div layout="row">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div>Logout</div>
   </div>
  </md-button>
 </div>

 <div layout="row" class="errorMessages">
  <div ng-show="loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.error" style="margin-top: 0px;">
   <label>{{loginPanelController.authService.tokenInfo.error.exceptionMessage}}</label>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="loginPanelController.error">
   <label>{{loginPanelController.error.data.Message}}</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713851/my-angularjs-ng-model-is-shared-across-browser-tabs-how-to-prevent-that)

Comment: I honestly can't figure out what he's talking about in that post. 

"In this application there are some configuration that can be change, for example, Sync Options. You must navigate to http://localhost:3001 then select Sync Option and disable all option but CodeSync."

This answer doesn't make any sense. I'm using Local IIS so http://localhost:3001 doesn't point anywhere.